# Echoing multiple php function outputs on one line

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use PHP for some randomization (colors & content) on my website.

I'm trying to make a grid with either half of the `div`s be automatically generated and a different `div` in the middle, but PHP auto-inserts a line break before and after the auto-generated content.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQEqX.jpg

As you can see, the bigger title box is pushed onto its own line instead of being wrapped by the other boxes, in order to create a grid formation with a larger box in the middle (that's why I can't use float, as it's only options are left or right.).

How can I fix this?

My PHP/HTML:

```
<div id="main">

    <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Home – Peter Ambos</h1>
    <?php

        $colors = array("#000", "#D8D8D8", "#909090");
        $content = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

        function create_icons($number, $colors, $content)
        {
            $created = "";

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
                shuffle($content);
                $selected = array_pop($content);
                $created = $created . '<div class="icon_wrapper">
                    <div class="icon l' . $i . '" style="background-color: ' . $colors[array_rand($colors)] . '" >
                        '. $selected . '
                    </div>
                </div>';
            }

            return $created;

        }

        echo create_icons(13, $colors, $content) . '<div class="title"></div>' . create_icons(13, $colors, $content);
    ?>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
#main {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5em 0 3em 0;
    width: 46.6em;
    height: 35.2em;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
}

.icon_wrapper {
    margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
}

.title {
    height: 5em;
    width: 21.4em;
    margin: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("/src/img/title.png");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div id="main">


    <div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l1">

                    G

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l2">

                    Z

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l3">

                    J

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l4">

                    R

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l5">

                    A

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l6">

                    H

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l7">

                    C

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l8">

                    I

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l9">

                    K

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l10">

                    X

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l11">

                    Q

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l12">

                    E

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l13">

                    N

                </div>
            </div><div class="title"></div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l1">

                    U

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l2">

                    L

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l3">

                    Q

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l4">

                    S

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l5">

                    V

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l6">

                    E

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l7">

                    X

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l8">

                    W

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l9">

                    Y

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l10">

                    Z

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #D8D8D8" class="icon l11">

                    B

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #000" class="icon l12">

                    F

                </div>
            </div><div class="icon_wrapper">
                <div style="background-color: #909090" class="icon l13">

                    M

                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: This post has been edited.

Comment: I am not sure what actually you want. But in order to remove line break you need to change width of title class 21.4em to 25.4em;

Comment: Can you post the source of the outputted html as well.

Comment: Could you just elaborate on what you want

Comment: @Max I added the outputted HTML. Hope it helps!

Comment: @user3514339 I added some more info on what I want to achieve + an Image of what it currently looks like. Hope it helps!

Comment: @peter ambos: - Yes i saw it. So which the part that you don't want

Comment: @user3514339 I'd like to have .title on one line with two of the .icon divs on either side, so as to make it into a grid with a larger title in the middle.

Comment: If you want to get rid of those linebreaks move the assignment of `$created` onto one line concatenate one string per line. The linebreaks are copied in from your php. Not sure if that will solve your problem

Comment: @Max Like this? `$created = $created . '<div class="icon_wrapper"><div class="icon l' . $i . '" style="background-color: ' . $colors[array_rand($colors)] . '" >'. $selected . '</div></div>';`

Comment: yeah, I think that will get rid of the line breaks at least

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem `<div>` by default it's 100% width and display block. Try to add in your css:

```
div {
    float:left;
}
```